# Using Data.Machine, how can you compose two ProcessT together that modifies two different states?

Tags: haskell, coroutine, transducer-machines

Let's say I have a process that modifies an underlying state that is an `Int`:

```
p1 :: ProcessT (State Int) Int Int
p1 = repeatedly $ do
   a <- await
   lift . modify $ (+a)
   yield a
```

And another that modifies an underlying state that is an `[Int]`:

```
p2 :: ProcessT (State [Int]) Int Bool
p2 = repeatedly $ do
   a <- await
   lift . modify $ (++[a])
   as <- get
   if length as > 3 then yield True else yield False
```

I want to compose them this way:

```
p3 = source [1...6] ~> p1 ~ p2
```

And run them like:

```
flip runState 0 . flip runState [] . runT $ p3
```

But I get this error:

```
   Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Int]'
   Expected type: ProcessT (State Int) Int c0
   Actual type: ProcessT (State [Int]) Int Bool
   In the second argument of `(~>)', namely `p2'
   In the expression: source [1 .. 6] ~> p1 ~> p2
```

Suggesting p1 and p2 should have the same type of underlying state. In fact, a little experiment shows that p1 and p2 are in fact modifying the **same** underlying state. How can I sidestep this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a bigger state and modify each computation to take a lens into a larger composite state for the system.

```
p1 :: (MonadState s m, Num a) => Lens' s a -> ProcessT m a a
p1 l = repeatedly $ do
   a <- await
   l += a
   yield a
```

You then just need to supply the larger composite state and appropriate lenses to drive the whole thing.

Comment: You could also provide a `mapProcessT` function so people could hoist a zoom really easily.

Comment: I'd be happy to take a patch adding it. ;)

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it I think it is already in there as `fit`.